# options_for_select to sort in alphabetical order in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the select for customer with options_for_select as below;

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :customer %><br>
    <%= f.select(:customer, options_for_select([['Z', 'Z'], ['T', 'T'], ['P', 'P'], ['B', 'B'], ['X', 'X'],['OTHERS', 'OTHERS']]).sort, {}, {class: "form-control", id: "recamount_customer"}) %>
</div>
```

It allows a user to select a customer but not in alphabetical order but I want to display it in alphabetical order.

I tried with .sort method but it did not work.

It gives me the error as `undefined method sort`

I searched thoroughly but unable to find anywhere.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `sort` is just in the wrong place; should be inside the parens to sort the `Array`. e.g. `options_for_select([['Z', 'Z'], ['T', 'T'], ['P', 'P'], ['B', 'B'], ['X', 'X'],['OTHERS', 'OTHERS']].sort)`

Comment: Yes, it is working as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the help and better post your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the .sort method was misplaced so it was throwing me the error.

When I placed .sort method properly it worked as expected, which is shown as below;

```
options_for_select([['Z', 'Z'], ['T', 'T'], ['P', 'P'], ['B', 'B'], ['X', 'X'],['OTHERS', 'OTHERS']].sort)
```